# Es posible aplicar un IN en la sentencia case, sql

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de asignar un nombre cuando se encuentra en una sentencia IN, utilizando la sentencia case, pero me indica error "missing expression".

Este es mi código:

```
CASE
    WHEN CODIGO = IN (476,130,33,506,44,439,49,20,4,634,148,132,42,7635,40,47,438)THEN 'BOGOTA'
    WHEN CODIGO = IN (636,70,339,341,435,509,83,437,102,521,100,542,629,526,91,94,86)THEN 'SUR'
    WHEN CODIGO = IN (60,63,162,62,416,417,411,450,274,545,518,92,519,504,430,432,52)THEN 'BOGOTA'
    else
        Pk_Interfaces.Fm_Traeregcod(SO.OFCCODIGO)
    end
as  regional
```

Comment: Quítale el `=`, utiliza directamente `IN`

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias, que pena era algo pequeño.